# XSL if test display content when it has values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, if-statement, umbraco

I have an `if test` where I want to display the content of the 'year' property with a comma when the property has values. This isn't working so I would be thankful for suggestions.

```
<xsl:if test="year != null">
     <xsl:value-of select="year"/>,
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I assumed null would be legal but clearly not in this case. I will read up some more! thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check `year` element presence simply using this expression:

```
<xsl:if test="year">
```

If you want to check that `year` element isn't empty:

```
<xsl:if test="year != ''">
```

Comment: how do i check if the element is empty? <xsl:if test="year = ''">, i've tried this but it does not work.. Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <xsl:if test="year != null">    
>      <xsl:value-of select="year"/>,    
> </xsl:if>
> ```

This would be `true()` if there is at least one `year` child of the current node and one `null` child of the current node whose string values aren't equal.

Most probably there isn't any `null` element in the XML document that you haven't shown...

**Use**:

```
<xsl:if test="year"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(year, ',')"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the not function

> not() Function — Returns the negation of its argument. If the argument is not a boolean value already, it is converted to a boolean value using the rules described in the boolean() function entry.

Example:

To demonstrate the not() function, we’ll use the same stylesheet and XML document we used for the boolean() function.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(year='')">
        <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>The element year is NULL</xsl:text>
    <xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Same for the if statement:

```
<xsl:if test="not(year='')">
    <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="year=''">
    <xsl:text>The element year is NULL</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```